# SSRS gives error 413 in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, sharepoint, reporting-services, http-status-code-413

I have a report in SQL Server Reporting Services in integrated mode (baked in to SharePoint) which has a multi choice dropdown that can have more than 1000 values. The report works as expected in IE 11 but in Chrome (latest version at this point) I get:

`Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 413`

This occurs when the dropdown is filled and the user selects all or some values and then closes the dropdown. It is intermittent so it does not always happen.

In our test environment, that is not in integrated mode, the report works in both in IE and Chrome.

For SharePoint we have reviewed the settings and all settings is in default. for example `maxReceivedMessageSize = ‘115343360’`, which would be enough I think. If Im not wrong, say the average character count in the dropdown is 15 and we have 1200 values. That would be about 36 MB of data to send to the server if assuming UTF (2 bytes) is used.

Comment: Did you ever make any progress on this?  I am intermittently running into the same issue.

Comment: No I have not Im sorry to say. As you can read in my question I thought it was related to when there was a lot of records sent to a dropdown. But that does not seem to be it. I was left to recommend the users to run the reports in IE instead.